# "ant" is not recognized as command in Windows

Tags: windows-7, command-line, android

This is my first time developing Android applications. I'm developing an Android app on Eclipse on Windows 7. I would like to run the Android app from the Windows 7 command line interface. I have my Android device connected to the PC.

The workspace directory that I use to store the Android project is

```
C:\Users\Guest\Desktop\Software Applications Development\Java\Android Moblie Applications Projects\Eclipse Indigo for Java EE x64-bit\project workspace
```

I opened the command line interface and I changed the working directory to the Android workspace directory.

```
cd C:\Users\Guest\Desktop\Software Applications Development\Java\Android Moblie Applications Projects\Eclipse Indigo for Java EE x64-bit\project workspace
```

I included Android sdk platform tools directory into the PATH environment variable.

```
c:\Users\admin\Android-sdks\platform-tools
```

Then I entered this into the Windows 7 command line interface:

```
ant debug
```

I have this error message on the cmd:

> ant is not recognised as an internal or external command, operatable program or batch file.

What is the solution to this problem?

Comment: If you `cd` to `...\android-sdks\platform-tools` does the command work? In other words, is `ant` in that directory?

Comment: Are there any typos, i.e. did you separated ....\platform-tools
with a semicolon?

Comment: There was no mistake

Answer (score 4):

`ant` is not a part of standard Android SDK setup. You'll have to install it.

- Download the latest ant zip file from [The Apache Ant Project](http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi).
- Extract the zip file to a folder, say `c:\ant\`
- Add `c:\ant` to your path environment variable

Once these are done, you'll be able to run ant from the command line

Comment: I still cant run ant despite downloading, extract an to folder and add to path environment variable. The windows that i ran on was 64-bit version. the android sdk supports 32-bit java jdk but not the 64 bit java jdk

Comment: by the way my workspace is located in the windows 7 guest account. I accessed the android workspace using the windows 7 administrator account.

Comment: @user1294663 the SDK supports 64-bit JDK ( I use the 64-bit JDK, fyi).

Comment: The android windows installer cannot proceed on to install the android sdk when i only installed the java 64-bit jdk version for windows 7 64-bit. When the android windows installer detects the 32-bit version of java jdk the android sdk can be installed. That was what i encountered.

Comment: I think i managed to run ant. i put the environment variable for apache ant directory with \bin. Then i ran ant debug . Now i see a different message . It says unable to locate tools.jar Expected to find it in C:\Program Files\ Java\jre7\lib\tools.jar Buildfile: build.xml does not exist build failed. Now what???

Comment: @user1294663 you should ask that as a separate question on [so]

Answer (score 2):

To assist with the above. verify from your Java installation directory that You have tools.jar; if not go and download http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html . after installation, you should see tools.jar in the lib subdirectory(i.e path_to_installation/java/jdkx.x.x/lib).
After that; you need to add the path to this new installation with : variable_name: JAVA_HOME and variable_value= path_to_installation/java/jdkx.x.x

Ant should not give you the JDK error again. If you already have the tools.jar, then just add the JAVA_HOME to point to the directory as mentioned above "path_to_installation/java/jdkx.x.x"-this assumes that tools.jar is some where in the jdkx.x.x directory
You may encounter issues with build.xml, check out this link: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBuildAnt/article.html

Note: x.x.x represents the version Number of your installation

Comment: I think that should be `JAVA_HOME`, not `JAV_HOME`.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the .android folder in your home directory ~/.android (Linux,Mac OS) or C:\Documents and Settings[User Name].android in Windows XP or C:\Users.android in Windows Vista or Windows 7, and delete the debug.keystore file. Then go to eclipse and clean the project, this will create a new debug.keystore file with default validity period 365 days.

For Linux user: Delete your debug certificate (debug.keystore and ddms.cfg) under ~/.android/debug.keystore

For Windows user: Delete your debug certificate (debug.keystore and ddms.cfg) under 
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator.android

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to download ANT. Here is the link https://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi.

Then extract your downloaded file in C:\Program Files\Ant Folder where Ant Folder is the folder name where I have extracted.

Now you have to set environment variables.
Right click on This PC > Properties > Advanced system settings > Environment Variables > User variables > New > Variable name:ANT_HOME & for Variable value:C:\Program Files\Ant Files\apache-ant-1.10.5 > OK.

Now goto System variables to add bin path.
System variables > double click on Path >New > C:\Program Files\Ant Files\apache-ant-1.10.5\bin > OK.

Now let's check whether it is installed correctly or not.
goto Command Prompt > and type ant -version.
That's it. Let me know if still getting any difficulties.